# Is there a good tutorial for creating an animation where different meshes replace each other?

Tags: animation

This seems like a basic question so please feel free to point me to where it has been answered, but I must not now how to google it because I can't find a good answer.

I have a scene with two types of objects in it pictured below,
1- A clear container object that will not change in any way
2- 40 nearly identical meshes that I'd like to replace each other in an animation.  I.e. Show the first one, hide it, show the second, hide it, etc...
[image]

I got this data from a different program.  Is there a good guide out there on how to do that?  Any tips?

Comment: Maybe look for "Morphing" objects with either the "Shrinkmap" modifier, with "Shape keys" or with particles forming to the desired shape. 

(Google: morph object blender ... (+ shrink map / shape keys / particles)

Comment: From my understanding the shrinkwrap morphing won't work because there's a different amount of objects/triangles/etc... in each mesh.  Am I correct that's a problem?  I think there's enough meshes in this that I don't need to worry about the transition between each one.... if it could just disappear and the next one comes in thats fine.

Comment: Hi @Joe, please note that this question falls short of expectations on [blender.se], please read [ask].  Specifically asking for a link to a tutorial constitutes a lack of research and googling.  With some editing you could turn this around.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out you can keyframe the visibility of the object in the render.  So I can turn off the visibilty of everything but the first one, then in the second frame turn off the visibility of everything but the second, etc...Like this link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8ZYW.jpg